# Which record caused INSERT IGNORE not to insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL, when an INSERT IGNORE does not insert anything, is it possible to get the row that caused INSERT IGNORE to "fail"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another and more correct approach is to use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

That is to change:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO the_table (id) VALUES (1);
```

To:

```
INSERT INTO the_table (id) VALUES (1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

This wil make no changes to the table, but the following call to LAST_INSERT_ID() will return either the id of the newly inserted item or the last result explicitly passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is to add a field which you can use as a flag, and then add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dup = dup+1` (or similar) to your query.